# Weblogic Rest Service implementation with Springservlet

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy my Rest based Web Service application onto Weblogic console 12C. For this, I have used Spring-Jersey implementation and Spring dependency injection.
While trying to access my services, I have to use /resources/* path of Weblogic because /rest/* is not working. Also, SpringServlet is not getting invoked, but Weblogic's own JAX-RS Jersey implementation is working. I have checked, during application startup, beans are getting created properly by spring.
Can anyone please provide a solution on how to use the my implementation rather than Weblogic's default JAX-RS solution.

web.xml.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TestWeb</display-name>
  <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>classpath:testWebContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
 <listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
 <listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
 </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.test.web.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

testWebContext.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <bean id="testWebService" class="com.test.web.service.TestWebServiceImpl">
  <property name="testWebBo" ref="testWebBo"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="testWebBo" class="com.test.web.bo.TestWebBOImpl"/>
 
 <bean name="destReader" init-method="readDestinations" class="com.test.web.util.DestinationReader"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert weblogic.xml file in your WEB-INF folder of your deployed app.

Here you have an example file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">  
 <library-ref>    
    <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>    
    <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>  
    <implementation-version>2.5.1</implementation-version>    
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
 </library-ref>
 <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.client.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.*</package-name> 
        <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.*</package-name>   
        <package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</package-name>
        <package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.aopalliance.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.annotation.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.inject.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>
        <package-name>jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javassist.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
    <context-root>your root name</context-root>
  </weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: No luck João Marcos. I added <package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</package-name> in this example weblogic.xml and used that.Any suggestion on what exactly to update in this weblogic.xml to get this working.

Comment: Try to check this page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP585
Hope it helps.